# Automatic fragment selection in Android

Tags: android, fragment

I'm just starting to learn fragments and have already gone through several tutorials. What I have noticed is that you can either replace existing fragments with another fragment, or reference an existing fragment and change UI stuff on it. I assume that there are methods for adding and deleting fragments as well.

But before I began to dive into learning fragments, I was under the assumption that Android had some kind of built-in fragment selection mechanism. If my app ran on a smartphone, it might select one fragment for the main screen and by swiping, the second fragment would be displayed. This would provide a kind of master/detail view. Then if you ran the same app on a tablet, both fragments would be shown simultaneously.

But clearly I must be wrong. Android probably doesn't have enough sophisticated logic built-in to determine screen sizes and automatically arrange the fragments in some optimized manner. Od does it? Or am I suppose to detect screen size and in code arrange my fragments in such a way that it optimizes screen usage? With a lot of different screen sizes, I suspect that I end up writng a lot of code to determine the layout for each size and arrange the fragments accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the different layouts based on the screen sizes, then you control the interaction between fragments in your source code.  So in the master/detail case, you will have one layout that handles tables and another layout that handles phones.  Android will automatically choose the layout file for the current device based on its size.  To see an example, start a new project in Eclipse, select master/detail and it will create a simple project exactly as described.

The following is taken from http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html

Depending on the screen size, the system applies a different main.xml layout file:

res/layout/main.xml for handsets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- "Fragment A" -->
    <fragment class="com.example.android.TitlesFragment"
              android:id="@+id/list_frag"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"/> </FrameLayout>
```

res/layout-large/main.xml for tablets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   android:orientation="horizontal"   android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"   android:id="@+id/frags">
    <!-- "Fragment A" -->   <fragment class="com.example.android.TitlesFragment"
            android:id="@+id/list_frag"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/titles_size"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <!-- "Fragment B" -->   <fragment class="com.example.android.DetailsFragment"
            android:id="@+id/details_frag"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" /> </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so here is how it works

You have a Container in your layout file of the activity and every time you add/replace a fragment you add it to that container.

Now if you wanted to show two different fragments side-by-side on a tablet. You would just create a separate XML that would contain two containers and you can handle it with your java very easily.

More reference from here [Android Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: Yes I understand that, but what you are saying is that I have to manually check for the current screen size and load the correct fragment layout? After all, Android has built-in screen size detection and selects resources accordingly. So why wouldn't they automatically select the correct fragment layout as well?

Comment: @AndroidDev No, Android does that for you. For Strings, there is String.xml file in Values folder, however, you can create values-lt folder place Strings.xml there, and translate everything to Lithuanian, in such case, and Android would automatically load Lithanian String.xml file when it detects Lithuanian system language. It's very similar with screen sizes and layouts, though I haven't had the pleasure of doing that much yet. [Read more here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)